# Determine availability of iCloud Key Value Store

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, icloud

I am working on OSX 10.8 application that uses iCloud Key Value store. It does **not** use Document storage.

I would like to determine if iCloud Key Value store is available for a user.

I was trying to use cloud like:

```
+ (BOOL)isCloudAvailable {
       id currentCloudToken = [NSFileManager defaultManager] ubiquityIdentityToken];
       return (currentCloudToken) ? YES : NO;
}
```

However, the call to `ubiquityIdentityToken` always returns nil, even when a user is logged into iCloud.

If I configure a Ubiquity Container as well as the key-value store then that call does work.

However, I've just had my app rejected by Apple review for indicating I need "Document & Data storage" without having any requirement in the app for it. I was simply using it to determine if iCloud was available.

Is there anyway to determine if iCloud key-value store alone is available to a user?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The iCloud Fundamentals guide has a table that [compares Document Storage to the Key-Value Store](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/General/Conceptual/iCloudDesignGuide/Chapters/iCloudFundametals.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012094-CH6-SW28)(Table 1-1).  In contrary to Mobile Documents, the Key Value Store should be considered *Always effectivly available*.

The `[NSUbiquitousKeyValueStore defaultStore]` also isn't `nil` when iCloud is not enabled, and it even stores key/value pairs - It just doesn't upload them to the iCloud server.
From the NSUbiquitousKeyValueStore's point of view there is little difference between *offline* and *logged-out*.

You also have to keep in mind that already stored values are pushed to the server as soon as the device attaches to the account. It might be necessary [to handle conflicts](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/General/Conceptual/iCloudDesignGuide/Chapters/DesigningForKey-ValueDataIniCloud.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012094-CH7-SW6) (if the default last-one-wins strategy doesn't work for your use case).

Comment: I am facing this issue - the problem is not when the user is LOGGED OUT of iCloud - instead the issue is when the user has gone to their Settings - iCloud - and scrolled down to the given app and switched it off. In that instance, [NSUbiquitousKeyValueStore defaultStore] does not allow you to save.  It will not update cached local or iCloud store.