# Getting id out of UbiquityIdentityToken's NSObject in Xamarin

Tags: xamarin.ios

I am wondering how to get an id out of UbiquityIdentityToken's NSObject in Xamarin. The [apple docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsfilemanager/1408036-ubiquityidentitytoken) says that the id is a property:

```
@property(nullable, readonly, copy) id<NSObject, NSCopying, NSCoding> ubiquityIdentityToken;
```

What get I in when debugging is:

[image]

How can I get a the id C# string out of the NSObject?

It is accessed like:

```
var id = NSFileManager.DefaultManager.UbiquityIdentityToken;
```

On a different device I get a different `Description` and `DebugDecription` they are suposed to be same. I have also read that the id from `UbiquityIdentityToken` is supposed to be null when in debug

Actually it acts more like a bool to check log in status. And can't be used as an identifier - which was my goal. Given in the answer of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13770974/what-is-the-main-difference-between-using-nsfilemanager-urlforubiquitycontainer) question:

---

I found that `DebugDescription` seem to work to use and is probably what it should look like

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried

```
var id = NSFileManager.DefaultManager.UbiquityIdentityToken.Description;
```

or

```
var id = NSFileManager.DefaultManager.UbiquityIdentityToken.DebugDescription;
```